# Check between variable in for loop

Tags: c

I don't understand why when I go to make a comparison between two unint8_t inside a for loop with an if without putting any printf I have that the comparison is not correct.

This code work, I don't have any error:

```
for (uint16_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        {
            printf("Position Value: %d -> read %d, expected %d \n", i, RxData[i], TxData[i]);
            if (TxData[i] != RxData[i])
            {
                error++;
            }
        }
```

This code doesn't work, I have error:

```
for (uint16_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (TxData[i] != RxData[i])
            {
                error++;
            }
        }
```

Work -> The two vectors have the same elements, so their comparison does not produce any errors.
Doesn't Work -> The two vectors have the same elements but their comparison is not successful and therefore the error variable is increased.

Error is a variable that is incremented if the comparison was not successful.

The behavior of the program changes by putting or not the printf.

Do you know the reason for this?
I also tried to put a while loop with a "continue" but I have the same problem.

Comment: What does it mean _'works'_ and _'doesn't work'_? What data do you supply, what results do you expect and what results do you get?

Comment: If the behavior is changing just because of a `printf` you may have undefined behavior somewhere in your program. We can only help you if you provide a [mcve] though.

Comment: Work -> The two vectors have the same elements, so their comparison does not produce any errors.
Doesn't Work -> The two vectors have the same elements but their comparison is not successful and therefore the error variable is increased.

Comment: Have you tried to run the program in a debugger? I would set a breakpoint at incrementing and see what the index value `i` is as well as the elements compared. BTW, are you sure the `error` variable is correctly initialized?

Comment: @CiaPan I can not use debugging because this firmware I am going to simulate it on an online platform that does not have a debug as you intend it. At most I can see the assembly code. The strange thing is that if I put the printf the code works correctly and if I remove it instead the code produces an error.

Comment: All-caps suggest that `BUFFER_SIZE` is a name of some constant, probably a macro. That probably defines a _maximum_ expected / allowed size of data. Are you sure the size of _actual data_ in buffers you compare equals that maximum?

Comment: Try adding a `printf` call *inside* the body of the `if` statement.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. why I have to "Try adding a printf call inside the body of the if statement. "?

Comment: @CiaPan, #define BUFFER_SIZE 256. uint8_t TxData[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint8_t RxData[BUFFER_SIZE];

Comment: You don't have to. Just use your debugger. What, your platform doesn't have a debugger? Then make do with what you have. If you cannot put a breakpoint in the code, put a `printf` *at the place where you would put a breakpoint*. You don't want `error++` to get executed, so you want to see what is going on *when* it gets executed.

Comment: Please add necessary details in your question,  as @mediocrevegetable1 asked you [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69602993/check-between-variable-in-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment123026752_69602993)  not in comments.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. ok I understand what do you mean, thanks

Comment: @CiaPan i have put it

Comment: That does not exactly look like a **minimal** example, right?

Comment: Is there any reason for using all those `continue`s? They don't seem to have any effect the way you use it.

Comment: I found the problem, look the answer!

Comment: How do you make sure all data is already received in RxData? Is it possible that your read access is still ongoing while you check the content? With a `printf` you add a delay that might be enough to wait for all data to be available.

Comment: @Gerhardh I get an interrupt when RxData has finished receiving data.

Comment: And this is clearly happening before you do the check?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes...

Comment: It seems that with printf you slow down the for loop and that makes it work.

Comment: @nicokingblogger You have an error somewhere in your program, but it's in a part of your code that you have not posted, so we can't see it, so we can't help you fix it.  When you find that adding or removing a `printf` call makes the program change its behavior, this often means you have an uninitialized variable somewhere.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was wrong to set the interrupt type. @SteveSummit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the comments on the original question I think what's going on here (***without clarification by OP this is conjecture***) is something like this:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256

// returns the actual number of bytes sent, stops and NUL terminator
int send_string(char const *buf, size_t bufsz);

// returns the actual number of bytes received
int receive_some_data(char *buf, size_t bufsz);

int test_interface_loopback()
{
    char TxData[BUFFER_SIZE] = "Test Data";
    char RxData[BUFFER_SIZE]; // left uninitialized

    // return values are ignored -> PROBLEM!
    send_some_data(TxData, BUFFER_SIZE);
    receive_some_data(RxData, BUFFER_SIZE);

    int error = 0;
    for( uint16_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++ )
    {
        if( TxData[i] != RxData[i] ){
            error++;
        }
    }
    return error;
}
```

The issue here is, that `send_some_data` will for some reason not transmit the whole 256 bytes, but perform only a short write. This might be for example, because it's assuming a C nul terminated string; but it could be also for other reasons like system buffer limitations, or maybe the bytes haves just been queued for sending, but weren't flushed out of the interface.

Either way, `receive_some_data` does not actually read 256 bytes, but less. And as such the remainder of `RxData` is left *uninitialized* and thus the comparison invokes *undefined behavior*.

The proper solution lies in taking into account the actual amount of data being valid in the two buffers.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use string but uint8_t array for TxData and RxData

Comment: @nicokingblogger for most C and C++ implementations `uint8_t` is *exactly* the same as `char`. Specifically the types in `stdint.h` are architecture dependent `typedef` toward primitive language types, that map the explicitly sized types to their less "specific" counterparts as defined in the underlying ABI.